# How do we show that the work done by a variable force (in one dimension) is the area under the $F$ vs. $x$ curve?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, calculus, displacement

In my physics textbook, to show that work is the area under the $F$ vs. $x$ curve, the author first writes the relation $dw = F dx$. This part makes sense to me. From there, the author writes, $$W = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F \,dx .$$ I'm not sure how the author made the jump from the first equation to the second. I interpreted it as taking the definite integral of both sides of the first equation but I'm not sure if that's right since I don't know how you go from dw to W.

Comment: Integrate both sides. The integral of dw from 0 to W equals W. More intuitively, integrating dw means adding up all the little bits of work. What do you get? The total work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not familiar with the integral calculus, but yes you are correct in your interpretation. "dw" means the infinitesimal amount of work done by the infinitesimal displacement "dx"

The integration process adds up all those pieces to give you the total work done.

(the sum of all the dw adds up to the total work done W)

In this instance IF the force is CONSTANT over the movement then you can rewrite it as

Work = Force x distance acted on

Answer (score 0):

You are integrating over both sides. You can break up an interval $[x_a,x_b]$ into many sample points $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_{n-1}<x_n$ with $x_1=x_a,x_n=x_b$. If we then assume the force between two close points $x_{i}$ and $x_{i+1}$ is constant than we can write the work between those points as
$$\Delta W_i=F(x_i)(x_{i+1}-x_{i})=F(x_i)\Delta x_i$$
Now sum over $i$:
\begin{align}
W\approx\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\Delta W_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}F(x_i)\Delta x_i
\end{align}
Taking the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$:
\begin{align}W=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\Delta W_i&=\int_{x_a}^{x_b}\mathrm dW\\
&=\int_{x_a}^{x_b} F(x)\,\mathrm dx\end{align}
We have to take the limit because we assumed the force is constant between two points $x_i,x_{i+1}$ which is only true in the limit.

Another way of seeing this is that when you integrate over a differential you just get the variable of the differential as asnwer, e.g. $\int\mathrm dw=w$. See for example this convoluted way to calculate the integral of $2x$
\begin{align}
\int 2x\, dx&=\int\mathrm d(x^2)\\
&=x^2
\end{align}
You could have also done the first step by a U-substitution with $U=x^2,\ \mathrm d U=2x\,\mathrm d x$.